# conical helix trajectory between two points

Tags: math, geometry, equation, spiral

I am not mathematical specialist, I need to know what is the ***equation*** that can be used to draw a conical helix trajectory between two points, A and B, starting from A. I have read the posts that are related to my question - [this for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38575522/create-a-spiral-between-two-cartesian-points-in-matlab) - but, I could not find the answer. 
[conical helix trajectory](https://preview.ibb.co/jCrszw/1_s2_0_S1090780703002830_gr3.gif)

Comment: You have not specified - what conical helix trajectory you want - there is infinity of such trajectories for two points. Is `kz` vector at your picture predefined?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

If you put together the pieces from the example you linked you should get the following:

If `A = (x1, y1, z1)` and `B = (x2, y2, z2)` and you want `rev` revolutions, then

```
C(t) = ( x1 + t*d*cos(2*pi*rev*t + t0), y1 + t*d*sin(2*pi*rev*t + t0), z1 + t*(z2 - z1) )
```

should give you a spiral with `C(0) = A` and `C(1) = B` where

`d = sqrt((x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2)`

and

`t0 = tan((y2 - y1)/(x1 - x2))`.